# Vim not setting `tex` filetype on startup

Tags: vim, tex

I noticed that if I open a non-existent HTML file with Vim, the filetype is set automatically to `html`:

```
$ vim foobar.html
:set filetype # --> filetype=html
```

On the other hand, the same does not happen with TeX. If I create a non-existent file the filetype is `plaintext`, and I have to save the file and reopen it to have it correctly set:

```
$ vim blabla.tex
:set filetype # --> filetype=plaintext
```

I also tried with Python, C, VimL, Javascript files and the filetype is always set right away. I don't know why this does not happen with TeX files.

The only thing I can think might interfere is `vim-latex`. Could that be possible? If so, how do I fix this problem?

If it might be of help, [here](https://github.com/rubik/dotfiles/blob/e96d7a301e43b8c8992528a592cc5f13b1d60631/.vimrc) is my not so long `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vim uses a giant heuristic to determine plaintex vs other variations of tex.

If you look in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` you will find the following function

```
" Choose context, plaintex, or tex (LaTeX) based on these rules:
" 1. Check the first line of the file for "%&<format>".
" 2. Check the first 1000 non-comment lines for LaTeX or ConTeXt keywords.
" 3. Default to "latex" or to g:tex_flavor, can be set in user's vimrc.
func! s:FTtex()
  let firstline = getline(1)
  if firstline =~ '^%&\s*\a\+'
    let format = tolower(matchstr(firstline, '\a\+'))
    let format = substitute(format, 'pdf', '', '')
    if format == 'tex'
      let format = 'plain'
    endif
  else
    " Default value, may be changed later:
    let format = exists("g:tex_flavor") ? g:tex_flavor : 'plain'
    " Save position, go to the top of the file, find first non-comment line.
    let save_cursor = getpos('.')
    call cursor(1,1)
    let firstNC = search('^\s*[^[:space:]%]', 'c', 1000)
    if firstNC " Check the next thousand lines for a LaTeX or ConTeXt keyword.
      let lpat = 'documentclass\>\|usepackage\>\|begin{\|newcommand\>\|renewcommand\>'
      let cpat = 'start\a\+\|setup\a\+\|usemodule\|enablemode\|enableregime\|setvariables\|useencoding\|usesymbols\|stelle\a\+\|verwende\a\+\|stel\a\+\|gebruik\a\+\|usa\a\+\|imposta\a\+\|regle\a\+\|utilisemodule\>'
      let kwline = search('^\s*\\\%(' . lpat . '\)\|^\s*\\\(' . cpat . '\)',
                              \ 'cnp', firstNC + 1000)
      if kwline == 1    " lpat matched
        let format = 'latex'
      elseif kwline == 2    " cpat matched
        let format = 'context'
      endif     " If neither matched, keep default set above.
      " let lline = search('^\s*\\\%(' . lpat . '\)', 'cn', firstNC + 1000)
      " let cline = search('^\s*\\\%(' . cpat . '\)', 'cn', firstNC + 1000)
      " if cline > 0
      "   let format = 'context'
      " endif
      " if lline > 0 && (cline == 0 || cline > lline)
      "   let format = 'tex'
      " endif
    endif " firstNC
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
  endif " firstline =~ '^%&\s*\a\+'

  " Translation from formats to file types.  TODO:  add AMSTeX, RevTex, others?
  if format == 'plain'
    setf plaintex
  elseif format == 'context'
    setf context
  else " probably LaTeX
    setf tex
  endif
  return
endfunc
```

This function determines which flavor of tex to use. If you look at it you can see that default value is taken from `g:tex_flavor` (if it exists, defaults to plain). If you set this variable to tex (in you vimrc), vim will default to the tex filetype.

```
let g:tex_flavor = 'tex'
```

Comment: Ahhh! I didn't know it was so complicated. This is actually the correct way to do it. Adding that line solves the problem!

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to automate the process you're doing manually.

Adding `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.tex set filetype=tex` to your `.vimrc` file will set `tex` filetype for each tex file, once you open them in vim.

Comment: Thanks! But why Vim is already doing this for all other filetypes, except TeX?

Comment: Maybe that your vim configuration doesn't have this in-built thing.

On my system, it's here, ``/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim``

My vim doesn't recognise *go* files in similar manner.

Comment: I don't know... Anyway, I'm adding this to my `.vimrc` so that the problem is solved.

Comment: Cool, anyway this is exactly how vim recognise these filetypes.

You can search in the file I mentioned earlier and you'll find that *tex* section is not there unlike other languages.

![vim-filetype](http://i.imgur.com/FhMWCCl.png)